# Maven project not working with other projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have a Java project that uses http common-logging.jar, httpclient-4.4-alpha1.jar, httpcore-4.4-alpha1.jar, httpmime-4.4-alpha1.jar. I converted my Java project to a Maven project and added the above jar files to my pom.xml. This is my XML file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MyClient</groupId>
<artifactId>MyClient</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>

 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
</build>

 </project>
```

I did Run As > Maven Clean and Run As > Maven Install and it built the project. It generated a jar file in the target folder called MyClient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.  I added this jar to another project that uses this jar file (to make HTTP calls) and I get the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody
```

Can someone tell me what is causing this? This seems to like a dependancy issue? Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you add MyClient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT to be used by the other project?

Comment: Why have you change the default source folder from `src/main/java` to `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`?

Answer (score 1):

Maven will not automatically package these dependencies into your jar file. These files are only used to compile the code and build the jar file itself. As the documentation for the [jar plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html) states:

> The resulting 'jar' file contains the compiled java class files as well as the files from src/main/resources.

You have a number of options:

1. Package your MyClient jar file as a "fat" jar using something like the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html)
2. Add the dependencies from the MyClient POM to the POM in the project that uses the jar file.
3. Use a maven multi-module project with a common parent so that transitive dependencies such as this are resolved between the projects.
4. Manually copy all of those jar files over when you copy the MyClient jar file

Comment: #2 defeats (or at least goes some way to defeating) the point of using Maven.  If this other project can't refer to an artefact published by the first project, then #1 seems a good choice.

Comment: An extra one: #5. Setup an in-house [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) repository and have the first project publish its artefacts there; refer to the published artefact in the second project's POM.  This will pull in the required transitive dependencies.